# Design Patterns for Objects in REST API's?

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, rest

I've built a REST API with the WCF Web API Preview and I wanna build a library with the classes that you pass to this API (Just to make the .Net developers life easier). The should be simple POCO classes without much functionality.

But on the receiver side it would make sense for me to add some functionality to these classes. I have an example below:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST")]
public Supertext.API.Order Create(Supertext.API.Order apiOrder)
{
```

And this is an example POCO class:

```
public class Order
{
    public string Service { get; set; }

    public string OrderTitle { get; set; }

    public string Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Now, what's a good way to extend this class on the server side?
I guess using a subclass would not work. 
Delegates?
Actually have two different versions of the class? One for clients and one for the server?

What do other people do?

Comment: I don't know Web API, but since your Order is a kinda DTO, shouldn't you leave it simple and clean, and instead build your functionality elsewhere? Or were you thinking things like validation etc?

Comment: Right, the question is what is the best and common way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with adding extra functionality to this POCO class is you are turning it into a domain object. The nature of this domain object will now be constrained by the fact that, essentially, this class acts as the definition of the interface into the operation. Changing details about this class will potentially break clients.

It is a far cleaner model to keep this class purely as a Data Transfer Object whose single responsibility is aiding the bridging of the wire format to objects and use a mapper such as [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map the data from the DTO to a real domain object. The real domain object is fully under your control and you can happily refactor it without threatening a cascading effect to your service consumers

Comment: Ok, but that also means that I basically have the same class with the same attributes twice, right? What about Partial classes? Is that a bad idea? I saw that here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716747.aspx

Comment: Well initially the classes may look very similar but that may change over time as you decide to represent the data internally differently than the wire format. Partial classes still leave a single class with multiple responsibilities. Separate classes give a much cleaner separation of concerns

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Will give that a try.

Comment: we have resource classes and domain classes. They are 95% the same at the moment. We use automapper to map between them. We also validate each separately. We use t4 to generate the resource classes from the domain classes